# Flutter: Tool for Creating a Theme

Tags: flutter, themes, flutter-test

What I am searching:
A tool or an open source project for creating a theme in flutter.
There must be a collection of all widgets on an app to try a theme on.

(Please help me to redirect this question to another place or refactor the question if it is not fitting the platforms standard)

Answer (score 3):

I heard of [Panache](https://rxlabz.github.io/panache/), where it basically gives you the final code after your review everything:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/rxlabz/panache)
- [Referral](https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter#styling)

And here is a screenshot from their website:
[image]

Comment: Yes that is the tool I am looking for. I am using an iPad and cant use this app sadly.

Answer (score 0):

[Panache](https://github.io/rxlabz/panache) is now available in browser : https://rxlabz.github.io/panache